# PHPStorm: изменение цвета и начертания шрифта в терминале

Tags: phpstorm

Когда открыл терминал, то ситуация оказалась такой:

[image: ...]

Заглянув в [доки](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/working-with-embedded-local-terminal.html#d477771e55), чтобы найти как изменить эти <s>ужасные</s> цвета, я обнаружил что это можно сделать по следующему пути:

> Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> Console Colors

Единственное, что повоздействовало, это под спойлером `ANSI Colors` цвета `Blue` и `Green` соответственно:

[image: ...]

Но странно то, что чекбокс `Bold` не был чёкнут у обоих цветов. Я изменил цвета на желаемые и чёкнул оба чекбокса: `Bold` и `Italic`; у каждого цвета, чтобы проверить что будет; но, как ни странно, никаких изменений кроме смены цвета не произошло; то есть даже `Italic` не сработал.

Как изменить их начертание шрифта: с `bold` на `normal`?